# save list of value in flask and reactjs using formdata

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to save array list of value in flask using form data.This is how i am sending list data from frontend

```
saveProjectDesign = () => {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('styleCheckedList', this.state.styleCheckedList);

    axios.post(this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/project/project/projectdesignsave', data, config)

        .then((response) => {
            console.log("response",response);
            if (response.data.status === "success") {
                openCustomNotifierSnackbar({ message: response.data.message, duration:3000, notifyType: 'success' });

            }
            if (response.data.status === "failed") {
                openCustomNotifierSnackbar({ message: response.data.message, duration:3000, notifyType: 'error' });
            }
        })
        .catch( (err)=> { console.log(err); });
};
```

here is the list data in styleCheckedList i am sending from frontend:

```
0: {styleId: "1"}
1: {styleId: "2"}
2: {styleId: "3"}
```

This is how tried to retrieve the value ins flask:

```
 styleListChecked = request.form.getlist("styleCheckedList")
```

But the value is printed in backend like this:

```
['[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]', '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]']
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the issue: `FormData`'s `append` method expects a string, not an array, not an object, but a string. When you passed in that array, JavaScript automatically called `.toString()` on it and got that ugly result with a `toString` of each element separated by commas. If you want to send an array, you need to append each element individually, as if it were from a POST from an HTML form

```js
for (let element of this.state.styleCheckedList) {
    data.append('styleCheckedList[]', element);
}
```

This treats each element as part of the array `styledCheckedList`. You would be done, but there's another problem. Now you're appending objects, not strings to the `FormData`, and that will just give you an array of `'[object Object]'` on server side. This is where it gets tricky.

It's not possible to send complex JavaScript objects through `FormData`. You'll have to either a) encode it in JSON with `JSON.stringify()` and decode on the server or b) if you only have the `styleId` key in each object, send just `element.styleId`.

If you don't care for any of this, `JSON.stringify()` the entire object in your current code and `JSON.loads()` on the server.

Good luck!